# Netbeans, Gradle and Jogl, crash

Tags: java, gradle, jogl, netbeans-8, segmentation-fault

I am trying to learn and implement Gradle in one of my [project](https://github.com/elect86/jgli).

I installed the Netbeans Gradle plugin and after looking a couple of tutorials (and running successfully a couple of test projects), I tried the big step. I successfully solved all the Jogl dependencies modifying the `build.gradle` script as follow:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = ''
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
    // Read more about repositories here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories
}

dependencies {
    // TODO: Add dependencies here ...
    // You can read more about how to add dependency here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'

    compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all-main:2.3.2'
    compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:nativewindow-main:2.3.2'
    compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:newt-main:2.3.2'
    compile 'org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt-main:2.3.2'
}
```

`settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'jgli'
```

But what it keeps crashing with the following output

```
Executing: gradle :run
Arguments: [-PmainClass=test.Main, -c, /home/elect/NetBeansProjects/jgli/settings.gradle]

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000002546, pid=18574, tid=139630779741952
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000002546
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/elect/NetBeansProjects/jgli/hs_err_pid18574.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 134

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

[This](https://gist.github.com/elect86/727c445c176686bec10e) is one of my last `hs_err.log`

My specs are:

ubuntu 15.04 x64,
Netbeans 8.0.2
Jogl 2.3.2

Please do note that without using Gradle my program runs without problems..

Do you have any idea what it could be?

Edit: investigating, I found out that under the `build` folder the package containing my shaders is missing.
[Here](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/455bc03045396658adeaa77a2199bba020151018211207/0b731bc7818dd152e84794df03e513fb20151018211207/9e858a) you can download my gradle jgli

Comment: send the report to http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Comment: Ok, I'll try. CommentPadding

Comment: Does it happen in command line without using Netbeans?

Comment: I guess I found some problems. At the compile time, Gradle did not copied under `build` my package containing the shaders... I inserted a link to my gradle project if you want to check by yourself what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially [solved](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/my-gradle-project-is-not-including-packages-containing-data-and-shaders/12316/2?u=elect86).

It works on windows, it keeps crashing on Linux

I needed to move them under the `resources` directory