# Gradle, error could not find or load main class 'test.Main'

Tags: java, gradle, find, program-entry-point, netbeans-8

I implemented Gradle on [one](https://github.com/elect86/jgli) of my projects. I use Netbeans 8.02 with the gradle plugin.

Structure is as it should be, sources are located under `jgli/src/main/java/`, resources under `jgli/src/main/resources/`

The Main class is `jgli/src/main/java/test/Main.java`

If I run it through the ide, it runs on windows, it [crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195461/netbeans-gradle-and-jogl-crash/33236797#33236797) on linux. That's why I am trying to run it through the console right now:

`java -jar jgli.jar`

But I keep getting:

> Error could not find or load main class 'test.Main'

This is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = ''
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
    // Read more about repositories here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories
}

dependencies {
    // TODO: Add dependencies here ...
    // You can read more about how to add dependency here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'

    compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all-main:2.3.2'
    compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:nativewindow-main:2.3.2'
    compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:newt-main:2.3.2'
    compile 'org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt-main:2.3.2'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'test.Main'
    }
}
```

I just modified the `dependecies` section and added the manifest part.

I tried to add `'test.Main'` to the ext.mainClass, but it changed nothing..

[Here](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/c731bf8e972241c7b73f9c43a616646a20151022075125/8ceeb7acf90bb54d62ad243d086dc22920151022075125/7cce94) you can download the jar.

This is my `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: test.Main
```

Main.class is properly located inside the jar.
Main.java has the package declaration `package test;`

Tried also

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'test.Main'
```

without success..

What am I missing?

Comment: could you check, whether your jar contains valid manifest file with the MainClass attribute and your Main class is provided in this jar?

Comment: Sure, `manifest` seems correct and the `Main.java` is there

Comment: Then check, whether your Main.java file has a package declaration in it, like `package test;`. Without it, the class will not be found

Comment: Yep, it has, anyway the ide would have triggered that before.

Comment: I've just found your git repo and sources of your Main class, seems that it implements some interface, which is provided in your dependencies. In that case, your dependencies must be in your class path, while you running your Main class. Try to provide `-cp` option to point the path with dependent jar

Comment: just added previews comment as an answer

Comment: I've grabbed your project, applied the application plugin and set `mainClassName = 'test.Main'` and it runs.  It crashes (OSX), but that's what you want anyway right?

Comment: Wait, for me it runs through NB only on windows. Therefore I am trying now by console. where did you run it from which os and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found your git [repository](https://github.com/elect86/jgli) and sources of your [Main class](https://github.com/elect86/jgli/blob/master/src/main/java/test/Main.java), seems that it implements some interface, which is provided in your dependencies:

```
import com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.GLEventListener;

public class Main implements GLEventListener, KeyListener {
  ...
```

Which are from some of your dependencies libs:

```
compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all-main:2.3.2'
compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:nativewindow-main:2.3.2'
compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:newt-main:2.3.2'
compile 'org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt-main:2.3.2'
```

In that case, your dependencies must be in your class path, while you running your Main class. Try to provide `-cp` option to point the path, where your dependecies could be found.

Comment: Should I just give `-cp folderContainingDependencyJars`, shouldn't I? Because it doesn't work yet

Comment: @elect due to javadoc "When you use the -jar option, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored." that means, you can't run it with -jar option

Comment: Uhm, ok, so what shall I do? Copy all my dependencies in the same folder of my jar?

Comment: classpath could combine number of jars and directories, so it could be something like `java -cp jgli.jar;/folder/to/deps/* test.Main` and no need to provide MainClass attribute in your manifest

Comment: @elect could you please provide the command you are trying to run?

Comment: Sure, `PS C:\Users\GBarbieri\Documents\NetBeansProjects\jgli\build\libs> java -cp .\jgli.jar; C:\Users\GBarbieri\Downloads\joga
mp-all-platforms\jogamp-all-platforms\jar\* test.Main`

Comment: @elect seems, you have a whitespaces in your path, for exampl after `;`  or `\joga mp-all-platforms\` in that case you have to wtite it within `"` like: `java -cp ".\jgli.jar;C:\Users\GBarbieri\Downloads\joga mp-all-platforms\jogamp-all-platforms\jar\*" test.Main` because in your case, the `-cp` value ends after the semicolon and path to lob folder is taken as a new parameter

Comment: I had to space to get the tab suggestions. Anyway it is kind of strange, I remove the space but I still get the error, I have to go with the `"`. Now it runs, but I still get an exception, `java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\GBarbieri\Documents\NetBeansProjects\jgli\build\libs\jgli.jar!\textures\ku
eken7_rgb8_srgb.dds`. Texture is located under `jgli/src/main/resources/textures/` and I load it inside java with the path `\textures\ku
eken7_rgb8_srgb.dds`, where am I wrong?

Comment: here you have to take a look at the way you try read it. since it's inside an archive, you can't just use a `File`, but have to use a streams to read it

Comment: Thanks, that worked on Windows. Do you know if on Linux I need to change anything in particular? Because this doesn't work `elect@elect-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/jgli/build/libs$ java -cp "jgli.jar;/home/elect/Downloads/jogamp-all-platforms/jar/*" test.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class test.Main
`

Comment: @elect I suppose, the reason is not that class `test.Main` was not found (commands are the same, may be just the privilegies differs), but was not loaded. As I can see, `org.jogamp.jogl` libs are depends on native libraries, that means, the may need some platform specific installation. May be you have to look for some platform specific questions about `org.jogamp.jogl` installation?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you set the main-class in your build file as follows:

```
mainClassName = 'package.MainClassName'
```

Do you pass it as Parameter? -> hasProperty
Then you had to run your build something like: gradle -PmainClass=MyClass build

Comment: `mainClassName` is used by `application` plugin, but not `java`. If you'll not apply this plugin, you'll get No such property exception, because this property will not be found.